# Xcode Could not find module 'xxxxx' for target 'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: arm64-apple-ios-simulator,

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I have an M1 pro mac, without Rosetta installed
I have a big project with many pods connected.
There is 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*] = arm64' for a project for Debug, and everything worked fine on Simulator.

The error appears when I connected the custom Swift Package and only for the simulator. On the device, there is no error, and all is working fine.

I have checked many helpless articles. Maybe you can guide me to fix this problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.